# IC identification - Analog Devices IC with top marking “H1N #847”

Tags: integrated-circuit, identification

Would you mind helping me to identify this IC? It has four pins on each side (total 16). I do not identify which firm this chip is.

The top marking says "H1N #847". It's used in a high-speed data collection card.

The chip is between the ADC and the data input. Maybe it is an AFE?
[image]

Comment: If it has four pins on each side, doesn't that mean that it has a total of 16 pins?

Comment: I always do mistakes in math... /(ㄒoㄒ)/~~

Answer (score 10):

Analog devices [ADA4927-1YCPZ](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ADA4927-1_4927-2.pdf). H1N marking stated in the datasheet.